# How do I implement an interface with multiple unnamed function members?

Tags: typescript

The js-quantities library has a swiftConverter() method that generates a function that converts numbers from one unit system to another (e.g., feet to meters). The function can take a `number`, or a `number[]`, and returns a converted `number` or `number[]` correspondingly.

The interface defined in `@types/js-quantities` is:

```
interface Converter {
    (sourceValue: number): number;
    (sourceValues: number[]): number[];
}
```

I would like to write a method that returns a value conforming to this interface. How do I do this?

You can't simply write a function of the form `(value: number | number[]): number | number[]`, because a function that maps `number | number[] => number | number[]` is subtly different from one that maps `number => number` and `number[] => number[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function with overloads will satisfy the interface:

```
interface Converter {
    (sourceValue: number): number;
    (sourceValues: number[]): number[];
}

function convert(sourceValue: number): number;
function convert(sourceValues: number[]): number[];
function convert(sourceValues: number | number[]): number | number[] {
  return sourceValues;
}

let conv: Converter;
conv = convert;
```

The implementation signature will still be free to do unsafe things, but that is the nature of overloads.

Or if you want you can have a method that implements a the interface. Since this interface has function signatures a class can't implement it, but a method of the class can provide all the necessary overloads.

```
class X {
  convert(sourceValue: number): number;
  convert(sourceValues: number[]): number[];
  convert(sourceValues: number | number[]): number | number[] {
    return sourceValues;
  }
}

let conv: Converter;
conv = new X().convert;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using `let` syntax? `function` syntax is not allowed within method definitions in strict mode.

Comment: @RISCfuture Um what strict mode does not allow functions? Unless you are using some lint rule `function` works with any ts compiler flag. If you want a method that implements this interface, the overloads are the same there just omit the `function` keyword, I can add a sample for that if you want

Comment: The error I'm getting is "TS1251: Function declarations are not allowed inside blocks in strict mode when targeting 'ES3' or 'ES5'. Class definitions are automatically in strict mode." I'm not clear on how to do it without the `function` keyword, since a variable name can only be `let`-defined once.

Comment: @RISCfuture posted a class version. If you are still  having issues please post the code, I am unsure how you are getting that error, all the code I posted works with all `strict` ts compiler options.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I declared a variable that implemented a new anonymous class, and returned the indirected method from that variable.

Comment: @RISCfuture Glad to help don't forget to mark as answered and upvote 